# Windows 8 reports different 802.11 types (n and g) at the same time

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

Running Windows8, I noticed a difference in what different parts of the system think the Wifi-connection type is: 802.11 n or g (g from Taskmanager, and n from the network status display).

Which is right, you suppose?

Platform:
Lenovo Ideacentre A720 i7, W8 with 
Realtek RTL8188CUS 802.11n wifi

Comment: You could always add a link to a screen shot. Then someone who has the right privs could add it. (Or you could add it after a few upvotes.)

Comment: You sure the adapter isn't a dual-band adapter? This would be the 2.4GhZ could be one standard and the 5.0GhZ band is another.  A screenshot would be nice and would make this question more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, your [wireless adapter](http://www.realtek.com/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=274) has both standards 802.11n and 802.11g.

Which both of those standards use the same frequency and I'm assuming your wireless router supports both of those frequencies. So there is nothing wrong there, it's just showing connectivity between the standards.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Wireless Adapter is N type, but your current connection is G type (Just take a look in Task Manager, near the Send and Receive Speed, you will see the connection type is G).

Your Access Point may currently set to N, but if you use TKIP with WPK2, result is till G connection instead of N.

I got the same problem too. Still figuring out how to fix this.

Comment: Since it does not answer the question, it should be probably changed to a comment, not an answer.